# Update help center page "help/dont-ask" to include links to both Closed and Deleted questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

As I went through the help section to assist a new user who didn't understand the off-topic reasons as they were stated at the time, I also found it asymmetric that we link to info about deleting questions without similarly linking to info about closing questions.

I therefore suggest to have the link in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask changed from ***"flagged [and possibly removed](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/deleted-questions)"*** to ***"[flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and possibly [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/deleted-questions)"***, so that:

- "flagged" links to "closed questions" and
- "removed" links to "removed questions".

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._" -Close-vote reasons

Comment: @GeorgeCummins And that is exactly what I placed as a comment on the original question; as I said, I found it. But new users don't know the first thing about close-vote reasons and apart from the sidebar, closing isn't mentioned on the dont-ask page. Which is why I suggest that the bullet-points are expanded and the word 'flagged' should link to closed-questions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell After editing out the part of the request that were identical to [this, now fixed question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197024/213634), I don't think my question is related to the question you link to.